# How to add multiple items in a list dynamically using linq in c#

Tags: c#, list, linq

I am trying to add multiple items in a list using console application in c#, But my list was adding with duplicate items.

Can anyone help me to resolve this isse?

Here is my piece of code.

```
public class Billionaire
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Country { get; set;}
    public int Income { get; set; }
}  

public static Billionaire billObj = new Billionaire();
public static List<Billionaire> Billionaires = new List<Billionaire>();

public static Billionaire billObj = new Billionaire();
public static List<Billionaire> Billionaires = new List<Billionaire>();
```

Comment: Could you please share the code where you are attempting to add to List ?

Comment: public static void addNewBillionaire()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter name:");
                billObj.Name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the income:");
                billObj.Income = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Enter country:");          
                billObj.Country = Console.ReadLine();
                Billionaires.Add(billObj);
            }
this is my code I need to add a list based on user selection, my list is adding duplicate items if i use the above code.

Comment: if user needs to add multiple items i am facing the above error

Comment: Please post that method in your post above

Comment: if you want to use List and not have duplicates, you will need to override the insert function. You can use Contains() method to see if the item already exists and if not, then insert it. There are many posts that talk about other ways besides List to store list of objects, such as a hashtable.

Comment: You can edit the question with code in comment, so that everybody can help you out. @SowmiyaPr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working on the same instance of `billObj` each time you call the method `addNewBillionaire`. The List would keep a reference to the same copy, which is updated when you call the method the second time.

To resolve it,You need to reinitialize billObj in your method (as given in the comments).

```
public static void addNewBillionaire() 
{ 
    billObj = new Billionaire();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter name:"); 
    billObj.Name = Console.ReadLine(); 
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the income:"); 
    billObj.Income = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
    Console.WriteLine("Enter country:"); 
    billObj.Country = Console.ReadLine(); 
    Billionaires.Add(billObj); 
}
```

If `billObj` isn't used elsewhere, a better approach would be to make billObj as local variable for the method